# how to prevent or clear a previous if statement result so it doesn't repeat or overwrite a new if statement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

NB: I'm really new to python and I'm self taught so forgive my unethical programming practices.

I'm trying to automate a series of actions for a web game [web game link](https://logigames.bet9ja.com/Games/Launcher?gameId=11000&provider=0&sid=&pff=1&skin=201). Using selenium it opens up the site and creates 3 lists containing 6 numbers from a table [web table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Qh8.png). The list is created by grabbing each element individually.

```
d1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                         '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/span[1]').text
d2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                         '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/span[2]').text
d3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                         '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/span[3]').text
d4 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                         '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/span[4]').text
d5 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                         '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/span[5]').text
d6 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                         '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/span[6]').text
```

here's what the lists look like.

```
list_t1 = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6]
list_t2 = [dw1, dw2, dw3, dw4, dw5, dw6]
list_t3 = [drw1, drw2, drw3, drw4, drw5, drw6]
```

the aim of the script is to select (click on) a number...1 through 49 [group of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyUQI.png)

```
one = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span')

two = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span')

three = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                  '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/span')

four = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                 '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/span')

five = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                 '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/span')

six = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[6]/span')

seven = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                  '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[7]/span')

eight = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                  '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[8]/span')

nine = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                 '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[9]/span')

ten = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[10]/span')

eleven = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                   '/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[11]/span')
.......all the way to 49
```

And then check if the selected number is present in the lists and depending on the number of lists the selected  number appears in a different value is sent to the textbox, values which i placed in this variables `main_textbox_value = '150'`,`second_textbox_value = '100'` and `third_textbox_value = '50'`

```
textbox_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]'
                                        '/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input')

 def clear_textbox():
   textbox_input.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') # This function is clears the textbox before inputting values 

textbox_value = textbox_input.get_attribute('value') # This gets the value in textbox
```

if the selected number is present in only `list_t1` input `second_textbox_value` (100) into the textbox

if the selected number is present in`list_t1` and `list_t2` only input `third_textbox_value` (50) into the textbox and

if the is selected number present in all 3 list or not present in either of the lists input `main_textbox_value` (150)

once this is complete select play

```
play_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/a')
```

then click on the previous selected number to deselect it

here the function that carries out this operation

```
    def selection_condition(select):
    found = [False, False, False]
    found[0] = select.text in list_t1
    found[1] = select.text in list_t2
    found[2] = select.text in list_t3

    if found == [True, True, True]:   # condition if "SELECT" appears all 3 lists
        if textbox_value not in main_textbox_value:  #  condition to check if the about to inputted value already 
            clear_textbox()                   exist in textbox and skip process of reinputting the same value 
            textbox_input.send_keys(main_textbox_value)  
            select.click()
            play_btn.click()
            select.click()
        else:
            select.click()
            play_btn.click()
            select.click()

    elif found == [True, True, False]:  # condition is SELECT shows up in 1st and 2nd list
        if textbox_value not in third_textbox_value: #  condition to check if the about to inputted value already 
            clear_textbox()                      exist in textbox and skip process of reinputting the same value 
            textbox_input.send_keys(third_textbox_value)
            select.click()
            play_btn.click()
            select.click()
        else:
            select.click()
            play_btn.click()
            select.click()
    elif found == [True, False, False]:  # condition if SELECT shows up in 1st list only
        if textbox_value not in second_textbox_value:   #  condition to check if the about to inputted value already 
            clear_textbox()                       exist in textbox and skip process of reinputting the same value 
            textbox_input.send_keys(second_textbox_value)
            select.click()
            play_btn.click()
            select.click()
        else:
            select.click()
            play_btn.click()
            select.click()
    else:
        if textbox_value not in main_textbox_value:  # condition if "SELECT" isn't present in any list
            clear_textbox()
            textbox_input.send_keys(main_textbox_value)
            select.click()
            play_btn.click()
            select.click()
        else:
            select.click()
            play_btn.click()
            select.click()
```

PS: The textbox is initially set to `main_textbox_value` (150)
everything works fine except after a selected number appears in the list and a condition is met Let's say  the list contain this values

```
list_t1 = ['21', '32', '16', '5', '12', '40']
list_t2 = ['17', '22', '33', '45', '1', '12']
list_t3 = ['23', '4', '16', '28', '42', '11']
```

and i ran the function:

```
    selection_condition(one)
    selection_condition(two)
    selection_condition(three)
    selection_condition(four)
    selection_condition(five)
    selection_condition(six)
    selection_condition(seven)
```

all the way to .........selection_condition(fourty_nine)

The code runs fine until `selection_condition(five)` which meets the condition to drop the value in the textbox to `second_textbox_value` (100) cause the number 5 appears in `list_t1` the only the problem is the textbox values stays at 100 upon the last number '49' is selected and the other if statement don't apply plus code runs without any errors.

```
So the code goes something like this
    selection_condition(one) ---------- 150 sent to textbox (correct)
    selection_condition(two) ---------- 150 sent to textbox(correct)
    selection_condition(three)---------- 150 sent to textbox(correct)
    selection_condition(four)---------- 150 sent to textbox(correct)
    selection_condition(five---------- 100 sent to textbox(correct)
    selection_condition(six)---------- 100 sent to textbox(wrong)
    selection_condition(seven)---------- 100 sent to textbox(wrong)
```

all to ........ `selection_condition(fourty_nine)` ---------- 100 sent to textbox(wrong)

Comment: One tip would be to avoid if/else style logic here...  break down the logic as case/switch  instead.  (and maybe use some bools)

Comment: Dear me, you REALLY need to learn about lists.  The Selenium `find` functions can return ALL the matching elements to you in a single list, which you can then operate using `for c in list_of_elements:`.

Comment: Your `clear_textbox` function does not actually clear the text box.  All it does is select all of the text within it.

Comment: What do you want to be sent to the textbox for six and seven?

Comment: The `main_textbox_value` (150) should have been sent for six and seven

Comment: @TimRoberts True the `clear_textbox` function does not actually clear the text box. i initially used the built in `clear() function` but was too slow it wasn't clearing the textbox as fast as the text were coming in then i created `def clear_textbox():    textbox_input.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')    stake_input.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)` then i realized that just selecting the text and inputting the value was much faster

Comment: I'm not sure `in` is what you want here.  Remember that if `main_textbox_value` is "100" and `textbox_value` is "1", that's a match and you won't take the `not in` path.